# tcpdump time precision how to?

Tags: tcpdump

I want to get tcpdump at low time resolution (at milliseconds) instead of default microseconds.

in tcpdump manual I got `-j` argument with acceptable precisions as '**host_lowprec**' and '**host_hiprec**'

```
tcpdump -i any -n -j host_lowprec "tcp"
```

I have 2 questions:

1. host_lowprec = ? precision
   and
   host_hiprec = ? precision
2. can I set precision to milliseconds or nanoseconds ? if yes how?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In answer to your first question:

[The tcpdump man page](http://www.tcpdump.org/manpages/tcpdump.1.html) says of the `-j` option:

> `-j` *tstamp_type*
>   `--time-stamp-type=`*tstamp_type*
>   Set the time stamp type for the capture to *tstamp_type*. The names to use for the time stamp types are given in [pcap-tstamp(7)](http://www.tcpdump.org/manpages/pcap-tstamp.7.html); not all the types listed there will necessarily be valid for any given interface.

and the pcap-tstamp(7) man page says:

> ... The time stamp types are listed here; the first value is the `#define` to use in code, the second value is the value returned by `pcap_tstamp_type_val_to_name()` and accepted by `pcap_tstamp_type_name_to_val()`.
>
> `PCAP_TSTAMP_HOST` - `host`
>   Time stamp provided by the host on which the capture is being done. The precision of this time stamp is unspecified; it might or might not be synchronized with the host operating system's clock.
>
> `PCAP_TSTAMP_HOST_LOWPREC` - `host_lowprec`
>   Time stamp provided by the host on which the capture is being done. This is a low-precision time stamp, synchronized with the host operating system's clock.
>
> `PCAP_TSTAMP_HOST_HIPREC` - `host_hiprec`
>   Time stamp provided by the host on which the capture is being done. This is a high-precision time stamp; it might or might not be synchronized with the host operating system's clock. It might be more expensive to fetch than `PCAP_TSTAMP_HOST_LOWPREC`.
>
> `PCAP_TSTAMP_ADAPTER` - `adapter`
>   Time stamp provided by the network adapter on which the capture is being done. This is a high-precision time stamp, synchronized with the host operating system's clock.
>
> `PCAP_TSTAMP_ADAPTER_UNSYNCED` - `adapter_unsynced`
>   Time stamp provided by the network adapter on which the capture is being done. This is a high-precision time stamp; it is not synchronized with the host operating system's clock.

Neither `host_lowprec` nor `host_hiprec` specify an exact precision.  The precision set with `-j` does ***NOT*** affect the way time stamps are stored in a capture file; they will be stored as seconds and microseconds, unless you have a newer version of tcpdump that supports the `--time-stamp-precision` option *and* the OS can deliver nanosecond time stamps, in which case they will be stored as seconds and nanoseconds and the file will have a different "magic number" so that tcpdump/Wireshark/etc. can read the time stamps properly.

All the `-j` option controls is how much of the microseconds (or nanoseconds) value is significant.

In answer to your second question:

There is no mechanism for storing times in pcap files as seconds and milliseconds, and there's no explicit option to request that the microseconds (or nanoseconds) value have only 3 significant figures.

There *is* an option to request that the time stamps be stored as seconds and nanoseconds.  If you are doing a live capture, this will work only if the operating system supports delivering seconds and nanoseconds time stamps when capturing; this currently only works on newer versions of Linux.

What is it that you are trying to accomplish here?

Comment: thanks for answer, me too read that man page. I had specific business requirement for dumps precision level.